# Is it possible to iterate over dictionary keys?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, onflow-cadence

The current method of accessing dictionary keys is through the use of the `<dictionary_name>.keys` field.

However, this may result in resource exhaustion for large dictionaries.

How can I iterate over the keys for the dictionary, instead of all the keys as an array?

Comment: This should be addressed to Cadence's support channels.

Comment: @Satyam Instead of posting a feature request, please rephrase into a question for what you are trying to achieve, like "How can I iterate over a dictionary in Cadence?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries have a [`fun forEachKey(_ function: ((K): Bool)): Void` function](https://developers.flow.com/cadence/language/values-and-types#dictionary-fields-and-functions).